# Ambiance gnome shell theme?

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, 19.10, ambiance

I just updated from ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 19.10, and I'm planning on moving to 20.04 when that comes out. I really like ambiance, and I love the soft charcoal colours. However, I can't find the gnome-shell theme that Ubuntu used back in 18.04. It looked great, and I really want it back. Is there a place I can nab it from?

Note: I already have the Ambiance window theme, just not the gnome-shell theme.

Comment: @PRATAP, It was the shell theme that came with 18.04. I don't have a link to it, since it was built-in.

Comment: @PRATAP, yes! I guess that's what I need. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my post...

Comment: thanks! Uh... how would I go about marking this as an answer...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Note: This is just a workaround..***

I have created a repository in git hub.. Download the files from there..

https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/UbuntuStyleCSS-for-19.10

You will get two files after Extraction from zip..

1. `Ubuntu` Directory
2. `ubuntu.css` original Ubuntu 18.04 style sheet for referencing colors

put the `Ubuntu` Directory in your preferred location for gnome-shell theme like

1. `$HOME/.themes/` or
2. `$HOME/.local/share/themes/` or
3. `/usr/share/themes/`

[image]

Refresh the gnome-shell with "Alt+F2 r Enter" method.

Open `gnome-tweaks` (If not yet installed.. install it by `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` command) and choose `Ubuntu` from the drop down under "Shell"

gnome-shell extension User Themes must be enabled for above to work.

[image]

Pics from Ubuntu 19.10 Practice:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted! :)

Comment: Welcome.. If you want some changes.. Refer the ubuntu.css file and edit only the colors from gnome-shell.css file..